# Accidentally erased .config

Tags: system, desktop, home

I accidentally erased .config

Many programs disappeared, all files, disappeared

Tried to recover data using RLinux and testdisk but with no success

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include what you *can* see? If you're stuck in a shell, then it will be important to look at the `/var/log/syslog` file to see if there are errors being reported.

Comment: ok i have access to the syslog files, what you want me to show exactly? thanks for your help (ps i'm pretty sure the last command i wrote before the "apocalypse" was "rm -rf .config" or ".cache", the intention was to remove protonvpn cache and config)